# c# to unmanaged c++ dll access violation / "frame not in module"

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, dll, visual-studio-2017

I have a C# application (in Unity3d mono) that is passing some data to c++ unmanaged DLL via C-API. It is passing in nested Struct that includes an array. Everything is fine until the C-API is closing when (at the `}` of the function) when I then get "Frame not in Module" message from VS2017, (if I "> Continue" I will get an access violation `0xC0000005` which the disassembly suggest could be missing a ptr - so probably a dereferencing error)

EDIT:  I think this could be that my source struct has a pointer to an array //EDIT

what causes this "Frame not in Module" ? - it's not very informative as a message

and what can I do about it?

My code...

I have a c# hierarchy of structs.

```
private struct Vector3
{
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float z;
}

private structure Location
{
    public Vector3 coords;
    public float distanceFromOrigin;
}

private struct Locations
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 10)]
    public Location[] locations;
}

private struct Scene
{
    public Locations cam1;
    public Locations cam2;
    public float timeInMilliSecs;
}
```

I'm instantiating the `Scene` and with `cam1` and `cam2` each gets an array of *10* Locations. Everything traces fine. Works as expected to this point and the data structure is populated with the correct data.

I'm passing the instance of `Scene` to an unmanaged DLL

```
[DllImport(dllname)]
private static extern void updateScene(Scene scene);
```

In my c++ I have

```
extern "C" {
    DLL_EXPORT void updateScene(Scene scene);
}
```

and an overload

```
void updateScene(Scene scene) {
    setSecene(scene); // this calls function fine but with erroneous data
}
```

and signatures for the equivalent structs

```
struct Vector3
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
}

struct Location
{
    Vector3 coords;
    float distanceFromOrigin;
}

struct Locations
{
    Location locations[10];
}

struct Scene
{
    Locations cam1;
    Locations cam2;
    float timeInMilliSecs;
}
```

The `Scene` struct is passed into the `C` with the correct data an goes to the c++. But then the problem occurs - i'm guessing this is a memory issue, but I'm not sure what to do about it.

Looking at the Disassembly is possibly shows it's a pointer issue?

`0000000040BDAE57 49 89 0B             mov         qword ptr [r11],rcx`

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I marshalled the whole nested structure across in a pointer - all changes in the c#

```
[DllImport(dllname, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void updateScene(IntPtr scene);
```

And then, before I call updateScene() I'm marshalling the scene struct

```
IntPtr  scenePtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(scene));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(scene, scenePtr , true);
updateScene(scenePtr);
```

everything else remained the same.

Answer (score 0):

Last time you say you don't change `CallingConvention`, so change the value to `Cdecl`.

Default value for `DllImportAttribute` is `WinApi` which doesn't clear the stack after function call.

And default value for C code is `__cdecl` which also doesn't clear the stack. It waits the caller to clear it.

That occurs the exception.

Comment: Have you tried to call updateScene/setSecene from a c++ project with the correct data?

Comment: Yes. That works fine.  Also if I convert to Location struct to have fixed Location1, Location2, etc and don't use the array, it works fine too. It's just the array!

Comment: Also worth noting, If I don't call setSecene(scene), it still happens - so it looks like a pointer issue between the c# and C

Comment: so I'm wondering is it because this nested structure is mixing it's values and it's pointers?

Comment: There's no pointer inside this structure. Another idea: check the structure size, use `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Scene))` in c# and `sizeof(struct Scene)` in c++, they should be equal.

Comment: thanks for your help, I posted an answer that I arrived after thinking about the error